# What is the difference between geometry and tf quaternions?

Tags: quaternion, geometry-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a geometry_msgs::Quaternion from two other (to create an Odometry message).
I've found that tf::Quaternion is a btQuaternion but it is not a geometry_msgs one.
I would like to know which is the difference and how can I work if I only have geometry_msgs::Quaternion inputs and outputs. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10643/what-is-the-difference-between-geometry-and-tf-quaternions?/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They represent the same data.  There are different libraries which support native processing of each of them.

There are conversion [methods](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h_source.html) such as to and from message datatypes for your convenience.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-07-20**:
Thank you !

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-11-14**:
What's the method for the geometry classes in tf2? I found my way to [tf2::convert](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf2/html/convert_8h.html), but that doesn't seem to do quite the right thing.

**Comment by [NickSpeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/4117/nickspeal/) on 2014-01-27**:
Hi can you please update the broken links?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-27**:
I've updated the links.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a noob i always are happy if a "nice" answer is provided. One, that can be copy-pasted. Because most likely someone will find this question when searching for a solution for a similar problem. So, if i'm correct, this should do the required trick:

Both ways this is needed at the very beginning of the code:

```
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
```

msg -> TF:

```
 quaternionMsgToTF(quat_msg , quat_tf);
```

tf -> msg

```
 quaternionTFToMsg(quat_tf , quat_msg);
```

Basically this is exactly what the answer above includes, just as a line of code for everyone who isn't (jet) able to read the code provided by the link.

---

Originally posted by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) with karma: 135 on 2018-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8